# repeat pattern wallpaper in TinyMCE editor

Tags: javascript, css, tinymce, tinymce-4

I have a function that changes the background of the tinymce editor, But I want to repeat a wallpaper or no. something similat to `background-repeat: repeat;` in CSS
How can I do this ? 
Here is the function :

```
function SettinymceImage(bg_image) {
var t = tinyMCE.get(0);
t.getBody().style.backgroundImage = 'url(https://my_path_to_wallpapers/'+bg_image+')'; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
function SettinymceImage(bg_image) {
    var t = tinyMCE.get(0);
    t.getBody().style.backgroundImage = 'url(https://my_path_to_wallpapers/'+bg_image+')';
    t.getBody().style.backgroundRepeat = "repeat";
}
```